# I'can reach my site after i try to install ssl certificate

Tags: apache, server, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, lamp

i have a LAMP server in digital ocean and i install it Wordpress and there is no problem in my site until 2 weeks ago, i bought ssl certificate from godaddy.com  and i did whatever 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority
this tutorial says. And it didin't work and after i did this things i cant reach my site anymore. So i try some other things but none of them works.

My site: http://gobokolektif.com/   or    https://gobokolektif.com/

**My "000-default.conf" looks like this:**

````
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName gobokolektif.com
        ServerAlias www.gobokolektif.com


      DocumentRoot /var/www/html
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
                Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName gobokolektif.com
        ServerAlias www.gobokolektif.com


    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
                Require all granted
    </Directory>


        ServerAdmin root@gobokolektif.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/ssl/intermediate.crt


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```
````

**My "default-ssl.conf" looks like this:**

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin root@localhost
                    ServerName gobokolektif.com:443

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            <Directory /var/www/html>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
                            Require all granted
                 </Directory>


            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                    SSLEngine on
                    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key


            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>


        </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**My ports.conf looks like this:**

```
Listen 80



<IfModule ssl_module>

Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**My "apache2.conf" looks like this:**

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


LogLevel warn


IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf


Include ports.conf


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>


AccessFileName .htaccess


<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>



LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent




IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf


IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
ServerName localhost
```

My ssl certtificates are in :  /etc/ssl/

**When i try to write "-f /var/log/apache2/error.log"  for what happening its says:**

```
    [Thu Aug 16 12:41:02.962437 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 9602] AH02565: Certificate and private key gobokolektif.com:443:0 from /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.crt and /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.key do not match
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Thu Aug 16 12:49:35.182760 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 9658] AH02565: Certificate and private key gobokolektif.com:443:0 from /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.crt and /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.key do not match
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Thu Aug 16 12:50:05.754441 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 9692] AH02565: Certificate and private key gobokolektif.com:443:0 from /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.crt and /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.key do not match
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Thu Aug 16 12:53:48.496877 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 9736] AH02565: Certificate and private key gobokolektif.com:443:0 from /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.crt and /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.key do not match
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Thu Aug 16 13:18:07.360925 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 9944] AH02565: Certificate and private key gobokolektif.com:443:0 from /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.crt and /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.key do not match
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

"service apache2 status"  this command's output is

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2018-08-16 11:13:56 UTC; 1h 4min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9056 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
  Process: 9037 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE

Aug 16 11:13:55 gobokolektif systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 16 11:13:55 gobokolektif systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Aug 16 11:13:56 gobokolektif apache2[9037]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server
Aug 16 11:13:56 gobokolektif apache2[9037]: Action 'start' failed.
Aug 16 11:13:56 gobokolektif apache2[9037]: The Apache error log may have more i
Aug 16 11:13:56 gobokolektif apache2[9037]:  *
Aug 16 11:13:56 gobokolektif apache2[9056]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server
Aug 16 11:13:56 gobokolektif apache2[9056]:  *
Aug 16 11:13:56 gobokolektif systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 16 11:14:16 gobokolektif systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit cannot be reloade
```

There is no problem with syntax. What can i do ?

I'm exhausted i dont know how to fix this mess, anybody can help me ?

Comment: From review: Please EDIT your question paste the error message as text instead of using an image. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks

Comment: Is Apache even running? Provide the output of `# service apache2 status`, `# apachectl -t`.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the new ssl certificate in 000-default.conf and **also** have the sample "snake oil" ssl certificate installed in default-ssl.conf.

Replace 
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
with
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/ssl/intermediate.crt

Then remove the block above from 000-default.conf

and restart apache.

Also, you can get free ssl certificates from letsencrypt.org. There's no reason you need to pay for one.

Comment: when u say "Then remove the block above from 000-default.conf" u mean this block:

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/ssl/intermediate.crt

Comment: The reference to the "snake oil" certificate needs to be replaced with the new certificates

Comment: okey i replace them in "default-ssl.conf" and restart apache but same still

Comment: Did you remove it from 000-default.conf?

Comment: yeah, i remove. And wrote "service apache2 restart" it's says nothing that's okey i think. But still i can't reach the site

Comment: You'll need to check the logs and see what it's complaining about.

Comment: i checked "tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log" with this and wrote the output in the main question. İs there any other log i have to check ?

Comment: The only log I see is the one you posted originally.  Restart again and post all the log entries from the time it starts, up to the end of the file.

Comment: I updated output can you look now  and if there is a way to show more log entry how?

Comment: Now it's complaining that "/etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.crt and /etc/ssl/gobokolektif.com.key do not match". You'll need to re-download your certificates. Also, this might help: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-fix-common-ssl-errors.htm

Comment: Okey man i did what u say. Now my keys are okey but this time i try to reach my site it says "This site can’t provide a secure connection" you can try yourself.

Comment: You've misconfigured something and your site is no longer serving https.